# receiving data from ajax request jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, http

I'm working on project to customize a book website, and i want to get book's reviews from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/api/) API,
my problem is that i don't receive anything from my Ajax request,
this is my code

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json',
    'contentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'data': {
        'key':'GHEH*******4B3w',
        'format':'json',
        'isbns':9782811215576,
    },
    'dataType':'jsonp',
    'success': function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    'error': function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
    }
});
```

i get a message like this on the browser console :

```
error
error
error
Failed to load for <script> element whose source is « https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json?callback=jQuery33108722523662348513_1538779243929&key=GH ...
```

but when i try to access to the link directly from the browser like this :

```
https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json?key=GHE*******B3w&format=json&isbns=9782811215576
```

it works perfectly

Comment: Yes i saw it, and i resolved it by adding dataType:jsonp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you problem is with the CORS(Cross-origin resource sharing
), goodreads.com doesn't `allow-control-allow-origin` for anyone, unless they had in there HTTP response an authorization for your domain to use their resources you won't be able to,

However there's a way around you can use `JSONP` or a CORS proxy

- if you script send it request to this proxy it'll work (but they have a quota, incase of overuse):

> https://crossorigin.me/https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json?key=GHE*******B3w&format=json&isbns=9782811215576